# How to preserve user input with textarea

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I'm writing a ROT13 webapp for a udacity course. Right now with my code, all I want to do is get a user input, and after the user enters it, print out the form again with the same input. So it kinda looks like nothing changed.

Here is my code. It doesn't seem to work. I think I should use the text variable better, but I can't figure out how.

Well to be more specific, it takes in the text, and then the text vanishes and I see the form again.

```
import webapp2

form="""<p style="font-size:40px"><b>Enter ROT13 text here: <br></b></p>
    <form method="post">
        <textarea rows="6" cols="60" type="text" name="text" value="%(text)s"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit"></input>
    </form>"""


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def write_form(self, text=""):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"text": text})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def post(self):
        user_words = self.request.get('text')
        self.write_form(user_words)

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)], debug = True)
```

PS: Whenever I paste my code, only the first line after the four spaces comes into the code block. I have to enter four spaces manually infront of each line after that. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Formatting hint: to indent multiple lines of code at once, highlight them all and press ctrl-k.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific than *"It doesn't seem to work"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The text disappears and I see the form again.

Answer (score 0):

Yusuf, the textarea tag of HTML does not support the 'value' attribute. Your code should work if you do the text substitution between the tags like below:

...
%(text)s

I also had this problem but found the answer on the Udacity forums:
https://discussions.udacity.com/t/hw2-1-preserving-user-input-in-textarea/68268/3

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it wrong in the post function
Use

```
def post(self):
    self.write_form()
```